# Series with $e^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}))^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ converges?

Comment: You could first try expanding $e^{1/n}$ to some order ($O(1/n^k)$). Presumably the value of $k$ will be related to the existence of $1/(2n^2)$ in your summand. Then simplify if possible, and see what happens from there. Haven't tried it so can't be 100% sure, but that's what I'd do first.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$e^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{2n^2}+\dfrac{1}{6n^3}+O(n^{-4})$$
and notice that: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ converges.